# PowerShell ADGroup details

Tags: powershell

How can I output the ADGroup name and the email address members of ADGroups with name of group starting with 'MY-GROUP*'
I manage to export all the desired groups but I'm struggling to get only the email.

```
> $adgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'MY-GROUP*'} | sort
> name
> 
> $data = foreach ($adgroup in $adgroups) {
>     $members = $adgroup | get-adgroupmember | sort name
>     foreach ($member in $members) {
>         [PSCustomObject]@{
>             Group   = $adgroup.name
>             Members = $member
>         }
>     } } $data | select Group, Members
```

The desired output would something like this :

```
| GroupName    | mail            |
| ---------    | --------------- |
| MY-GROUP-1   | memberA@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-1   | memberB@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-1   | memberC@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-2   | memberA@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-2   | memberD@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-2   | memberF@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-3   | memberI@mail.com|
| MY-GROUP-3   | memberJ@mail.com|
```

Comment: You will need to start by retrieving a list of groups, and then retrieving the members of each group. I commend your attention to the output of [Get-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps) and the output of [Get-Help about_ActiveDirectory_Filter](http://powershellhelp.space/about/about_activedirectory_filter-psv5.php).

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me :

```
$adgroups = Get-ADGroup -Filter {Name -like 'MY-GROUP-*'} | sort name

$data = foreach ($adgroup in $adgroups) {
    $members = $adgroup | get-adgroupmember | get-aduser -Properties mail | select mail
    foreach ($member in $members) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Group   = $adgroup.name
            Members = $member
        }
    }
}
$data | select Group, Members
```

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` can also return other objects besides users, like computers and groups. (you should test for that before going through to Get-AdUser). Also, `-Filter` is a query **string**, not a scriptblock.